# How to insert wp_users ->user login name to wp_terms when a new user registering?

Tags: wordpress

i need to insert wp_users -> user_login field to wp_terms name and slugs field,when a new user registering.

my requirement is admin needs to assign posts to specific users, that is admin need to add a post to user1 ,but user2 should not see that.for this i created a custom post and add taxonomy for that.And the terms are users Usernames .so i need to list the usernames of the users as terms in the taxonomy.when a new user is registered his username should updated in the wp_terms table also,so i will get the usernames as terms.

i stucked here .please suggest some solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add_action( 'user_register', 'yg_user_registration', 10, 1 );

function yg_user_registration( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
   $user_name = $user_info->user_login;

wp_insert_term( $user_name, 'category', array() );

}

it's working

Comment: how to delete the term that was inserted in to the taxonomy when a user deleted ?